# D3 JSON diagram shapes

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm creating a diagram with D3 and JSON which is based on this:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

The difference is, I also want to have different shapes for nodes (not just circles, but for example, trianges.)

I have a attribute in the JSON file that says something like "shape":"triangle".

How do I update that index.html file so that I can get different shapes to be displayed?

Really urgently need assistance...any help/advice really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Trying modifying this line to be what you want, which is currently drawing a circle:

node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

Answer (score 0):

D3 has some built in SVG helpers for drawing symbols:  [d3.svg.symbol](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol).  AS @pfrank suggests, you should be able to append a `path` instead of a `circle` and set the `d` attribute to the output of the symbol helper configured to whatever shape you want.

Comment: Thanks...I'll look into it...still haven't figured it out yet! ><